# When we talk about random variables being vectors, what is the vector space they inhabit?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, vectors, random-variables

I understand framing random variables in terms of vectors can be useful, and has a lot of neat intuitive insights (correlation as the cosine between centered vectors etc.). But in a less hand-wavey sense what is this vector space? In particular, what are its dimensions? What determines how many there are? Intuitively it seems like it corresponds to how many discrete outcomes there are in the probability space, but I’m not sure if that’s a good intuition

Comment: I'd say usually its $L^2$ space with respect to a problem-specific probability measure

Comment: It's infinite dimensional except when the probability space is quite limited. The dimensions themselves can't really be conveniently identified since there isn't really any canonical basis. Also there is no need to impose any integrability constraint, though there is much more "geometry" if you look at $L^2$ (finite variance).

Comment: Some actual good linear algebraic questions are "what is the base field?", "what does it mean to add two random variables?", "what does it mean to multiply a random variable by a scalar?", "what is the dimension of the space?", "what does it mean to take the norm of a random variable", and "what does it mean to take the inner product of two random variables?". In the case of centered random variables with finite variance, you know good answers to all of these questions.

Comment: @Ian thanks - so for a toy example would the space for variables on a 6-sided dice just be a 6d space, with the inner-product space differing depending on things like the bias of the dice?

Comment: Technically yes, but that is not normally how we build probability spaces. Probability spaces are usually massive abstract spaces that are suitable for defining all the random variables we want to define together. To use your example, one reason why is that this space does not let you roll the die a second time.